# How to update multiple fields of class at once in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm new to dart and flutter and I want to create a method that update multiple fields at once.

For example, suppose there is a class named `User`, and it looks like this:

```
class User {
  int      id;
  String   password;
  String   firstName;
  String   lastName;
  String   nickName;
  String   gender;
  DateTime birthday;
  String   phoneNumber;
  String   address;

  ...
}
```

In this example, an instance of `User` will have a lot of fields and it's awkward to update multiple fields if you don't intend to update all of them.

So, when you update only `password`, `nickName`, `phoneNumber` and `address`, instead of reassigning a new User instance like this:

```
user = User(
  id          : 0,
  password    : 'xxxxxxx',
  firstName   : 'Hanako',
  lastName    : 'Tanaka',
  nickName    : 'Tanako',
  gender      : 'female',
  birthday    : DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
  phoneNumber : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  address     : 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
);
```

I want to update them like this:

```
user.updateUser({
  password    : 'xxxxxx',
  nickName    : 'Tanako',
  phoneNumber : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  address     : 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
});
```

Please tell me if there is a way to create a method that update multiple fields at once like this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this like this

```
class User {
int id;
String password;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String nickName;
String gender;
DateTime birthday;
String phoneNumber;
String address;

User({
  required this.id,
  required this.password,
  required this.firstName,
  required this.lastName,
  required this.nickName,
  required this.gender,
  required this.birthday,
  required this.phoneNumber,
  required this.address,
});

updateUser({
  int? id,
  String? password,
  String? firstName,
  String? lastName,
  String? nickName,
  String? gender,
  DateTime? birthday,
  String? phoneNumber,
  String? address,
}) {
  this.id = id ?? this.id;
  this.password = password ?? this.password;
  this.firstName = firstName ?? this.firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName ?? this.lastName;
  this.nickName = nickName ?? this.nickName;
  this.gender = gender ?? this.gender;
  this.birthday = birthday ?? this.birthday;
  this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber ?? this.phoneNumber;
  this.address = address ?? this.address;
}
}
```

when you don't give a property name it will not update that field of the object for example if you want to update only firstName and lastName you can do it like this

```
user.updateUser(firstName:"Nao",lastName:"COMATSU");
```

and all other fields will not be updated